# if ((123 / 1000) > 0) returns false

Tags: c#, numbers

I recently came across what seems to puzzle my logic of maths in a piece of code

```
if((123/1000) > 0)
```

For some reason, C# is claiming that this is false but if one were to think logically, 0.123 *is* larger than 0.

Is there any reason that it is claiming that 0.123 is smaller than 0?

I have read that there will be a comparison issue with double that is base 2 and it would be better to use decimal which is base 10.

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: int/int is always int... Hey this is a good song idea...

Comment: what does if((123.0/1000.0) > 0.0) give you?

Comment: alteast one of the operand should be a floating point number, you can specify `if((123d/1000) > 0)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your fallacy is that you think the result is `0.123` whereas it is `0` instead.

C# (and many other C-like languages) define that operations involving two integral numbers always return an integer, so `1 + 1` will return `2`, not `2.0` and `3 / 2` will return `1`, not `1.5`. The fractional part in this case is simply discarded, so it always rounds towards zero (i.e. for positive results it rounds down, for negative ones it rounds up).

While this is perhaps a little counter-intuitive the main reason for this is language/compiler simplicity, execution speed (because you do not need to figure out what type the result has), the ability to use operators like `/=` which wouldn't work if the result was a different type) and historical legacy and inertia.

To solve this you need to make at least one of your operands a floating-point number (the other one will follow suit automatically, as will the result):

```
// either
if (123.0 / 1000 > 0)
// or
if (123 / 1000.0 > 0)
// or
if (123.0 / 1000.0 > 0)
```

If you have variables instead you may need a typecast (as you cannot simply append `.0` :-)):

```
if ((double)a / b > 0)
```

And the usual advice holds true here as well: When programming, rarely trust your intuition because computers are strange machines and programming languages sometimes even stranger. Printing the result somewhere or assigning it to a variable and checking in the debugger would have shown you that your expectations were off :-)

Comment: I will choose yours as the answer as it is the most comprehensive. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 9):

123 and 1000 are integers, and the result is less than 1 so it's rounded to 0.  Use this:

```
123.0/1000.0 > 0.0
```

And it will use double-precision, i.e. you can have a fraction!

Answer (score 4):

Since `123` and `1000` are [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx), result **must** be [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx). But since the result is less than `1`, it is automatically rounded to `0`.

You shoud make at least of this numbers is floating-point numbers.

```
if(123.0/1000.0 > 0.0)
{
   if((123.0/1000) > 0)
   {
       if((123/1000.0) > 0)
       {
             Console.WriteLine("True"); // Prints True
       }
   }
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/sr6ZzX).

Check out this question also [Possible Loss of Fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061334/possible-loss-of-fraction)

Comment: Vomit.  You're exposing someone new to coding quadruple-indented single-line `if`s.  Vomit, and no further comment

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I wrote it as an example with my explanation. But how do you know he is new to coding? It is just assuming. And I believe using nested `if's` is not only for experienced developers.. At leaset doesn't deserve downvote anyway..

Comment: It's a low quality question with typos, low quality code and low quality comments.  I can't recommend this answer, I can only see flaws.  Hence, downvote

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I agree. Also `if` is suggested to be written with `if{ }` :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though this has been answered, no one has given the good point of view to this problem, so I wanted to make it more clear :

If you are `dividing` or `multiplying` `int` and `float` you will get the results like this:

```
int/int => int
float/int => float
int/float => float
```

so if you are dividing:

```
123/1000 => 0 (as there is no int number 0.123, it will then set to 0)
123.0/1000 => 0.123 (this dividing is basically saying that I need a float result of dividing)
123/1000.0 => 0.123 (this says the same as previous)
```

So the rule is basically - if you are using an type that is on "upper" level that the one it is used, then the calculation will be translated to that "parent" type. But this can't be said in general, as if floating type is used, it will always be transfered to float number. Here are more examples:

```
long/int => long
double/float => double
double/int => double
```

And if you want to have an **answer** to your question, the answer would be to put:

```
if(((float)123/1000) > 0)
```

or

```
if(((double)123/1000) > 0)
```

So it would calculate always the float number (0.123 number)

Answer (score 1):

`int / int` is an `int` - which means that `123/1000` is `0` and not `0.123` as you might expect -

since 0 is not greater than 0, expression evaluates to false!

The fix is to make one of the integers as a double -

```
if(123.0 / 1000 > 0) <- true
if(123 / 1000.0 > 0) <- true
if(123.0 / 1000.0 > 0) <- true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if((123.0/1000) > 0)
```

You are trying to divide the `int` by the `int`. So you get integer division. But you need to use  double.

And if you want to devide int variables and get a double use this:

```
 double doubleNum = (double)intNum1/(double)intNum2;
```

Answer (score -1):

When doing a divide with only integer values, the result will also be an integer.

If I recall correctly the part after the decimal point gets stripped out.

So you code gets compiled into something like:

```
a = int(123/1000)   <--- evaluates to 0.
if (a > 0) ....       <--- false
```

The solutions as per @algreat answer is to force one of the operands to be double (by adding `.0`.  This will force the result to be float as well.

Comment: -1: `floor` is a C function, and adding `.0` does not make it a float, it makes it a `double`