# C# Avoiding Loss of fraction

Tags: c#

Let's say I have these products and an order total of `21565` after a discount is applied:

```
var data = new List<OrderItem>{
    new OrderItem {
      PriceCents = 10000,
      Qty = 1
    }, 
    new OrderItem {
      PriceCents = 5673,
      Qty = 2
    }, 
    new OrderItem {
      PriceCents = 5000,
      Qty = 1
    },
};
```

How can I distribute a subtraction so that when a sum of `PriceCents * Qty` is done, it equals the order total of `21565`?

I currently have this:

```
var orderItemsTotalCents = data.Sum(x => x.PriceCents * x.Qty);
var checkoutTotalDiff = orderTotalCents - orderItemsTotalCents;
var amountToSubtract = checkoutTotalDiff / (decimal)data.Count;
foreach (var orderItem in data)
{
    orderItem.PriceCents += Convert.ToInt64(amountToSubtract / (decimal)orderItem.Qty);
}
```

But the issue I have is a loss of fraction. `21564` is the sum of `PriceCents * Qty` instead of `21565`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible Loss of Fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061334/possible-loss-of-fraction)

Comment: Basically you need nominator or denominator of your fraction to be float or double to get the correct value

Comment: @demonplus OP has cast to `decimal`, so no. The problem here is in the logic, `Convert.ToInt64` will result in the lost cents in quite a lot of cases.

Comment: The suggested post does not answer my question. I'm aware of the loss of fraction when dividing but I need to accommodate for it so that it's not totally lost. The addition I could make is to find what the loss amount is and then apply that difference to the first item - but I'm looking for a cleaner solution if possible.

Comment: @GuruStron agree Convert.ToInt64 gives that problem

Comment: You need to change `PriceCents` to be a decimal

Comment: @Charlieface I can't. It's a 3rd party API call.

Comment: Then you can't simply do the math. Distributing 1 cent on 3 items will round the cent away if its an integer. In that case of a diff i would suggest distribution 1 cent randomly on one(or more if the diff is >1) on the items.

Comment: _How can I distribute a subtraction so that when a sum of PriceCents * Qty is done, it equals the order total of 21565?_: What does this mean? You randomly decided on an amount to discount the order and you want the user to believe that you've discounted each item by a certain percentage?